# backgroundColor of UIImageView is ignored on iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, ios7, uibackgroundcolor

Before iOS7, a code like this worked fine on UIImageView's subclass. 
But not working any more.

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect) frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I also checked this on InterfaceBuilder.
And again, the value of backgroundColor of UIImageView won't change anything...
All of those works on UIView...
So, what happened to its UIImageView? Isn't it still a subclass of UIView?
Or is this property disabled from iOS7?
Or is there any new properties that I must set something to make this work?

Probably this code describe the issue better:

```
UIImageView *imageView =[ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Changing the value of backgroundColor works when it doesn't have image property.
But then it is no longer backgroundColor...

Comment: How are you creating the image view? What size is it and what size is the image? What content mode are you using?

Comment: Both the frameSize of imageView and the imageSize are 35x35. I don't set contentMode as to apply its default value (UIViewContentModeScaleToFill). To create the subclass of UIImageView, it actually calls initWithFrame: although it is a little customized to set two additional values. (initWithFrame:commandTag:mainController:) Since I'm using this as a button, the color is set afterwards, not in initWithFrame.

Comment: So if the image is the same size as the view, when do you expect to see the background colour?

Comment: Sorry I don't know if I get your point but, the change of background color should be seen through the image. and it worked that way up until iOS6.

Comment: So the image is part transparent? Have you tried it without adding the image?

Comment: Well, I'm actually checking it now. I have never set alpha on UIImage that is set on UIImageView. It worked as I expected, but that might be the reason that is not working on iOS7.

Comment: Oh- shoot! UIImage is not a subclass of UIView but NSObject, so there is no way to set such values... Now I'm confused why it worked before. This thing worked since iOS 3 until 6...

Comment: I'm talking about the image file you are loading into the `UIImage` that goes into your `UIImageView`. The image file should have transparency for what you're talking about. And if you don't add the image you should see the background colour.

Comment: Without the image, the color changes. The image should have transparency. As a matter of fact, if I set this UIImageView on UIView and change the UIView's backgroundColor, the change appears through the image. But it has the same effect by just changing backgroundColor of UIImageView before.

Answer (score 0):

If your UIImageView is coming from a .xib/.storyboard, `initWithCoder:` will be called instead of `initWithFrame:`. As an example, I put together this little UIImageView subclass, and then put a TestImageView with centered content in a view controller's view inside a storyboard. The TestImageView's background color is set to red in the storyboard.

```
@implementation TestImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    NSLog(@"setting background color to %@", backgroundColor);
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}

@end
```

Running the app created this output:

```
setting background color to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1
setting background color to UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1
```

And this on screen:

[image]

As you can see, setBackgroundColor was first called with the red color from the storyboard (this happens in `[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]`), and then with the green color from initWithCoder.

Comment: Wow! thank you very much. But I don't use storyboard, no interface builder but everything is made by code. In any case, is backgroundColor still works on iOS7?? What I did worked fine until iOS7 with XCode5.

Comment: Hey Greg, I have another question. When you change the background color, can that change be seen through the image as well? I believe it was possible before iOS7. My app actually worked that way.

Comment: Yes, the background color shows through the transparent portions of the image in the image view. I updated the image in my app to have a transparent area in the center, and updated the screenshot to show how it looks.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is it possible to change the image's alpha value something in the middle? right now it is background or image, but can you mix it? I tell you the purpose. I'm using UIImageView as a button and change the backgroundColor for ON/OFF. That's why I need to see the change of color through the image.

Comment: Yes, I created a new png with 50% opacity, and the green background blends through the png in the image view. (I didn't bother uploading a new image to the answer.)

Comment: Where did you change the opacity? is it the image itself or in the code like alpha value? Actually, code like:
UIImageView *imageView =[ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
does work?
It used to work as I expected. It still works if I don't add image property. But then it is no longer backgroundColor...

Comment: I changed the opacity of the image itself. Each pixel in the image has an alpha value of 0.5.

Comment: I see, thanks. I still want to know if the updated sample code works or not. But now at least I have a way to make things work. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Just for an update. 
As both Wain and Greg suggested, 
**changing the opacity of the image itself solved the problem**.
Just don't know why it didn't matter before iOS7, but matters after
and am still wondering it might be just a issue of iOS7 itself. Anyway, although I have  nearly 200 images to work, it's better to start modifying them than just waiting for Apple's answer.
Thank you guy for your help!